# The name of a SciFi story I read in 1980 about a sleeper person

Tags: story-identification

I have been searching for this story for years. This is what I remember:  It's about Earth and either unknown or known to its population, it is under some type of control. Possibly alien. I remember a person or people who were sleeper agents that either awoke to discover this rule or control or had their memory turned on. Then I remember it culminated in this person or persons discovering an underground facility or weapon which may have been in England. And while this person or persons were trying to activate something in this facility or bunker, the outside forces were trying to blast / dig down to try to stop them. I seem to remember a device or missile in this facility or bunker.

I know this is piecemeal, but it has grown foggy over the years. I read it in either a stand alone novel or as a short story. It was from the library at Kaneohe Marine Corps Air Station and the year was 1980. I seem to remember a rocket on the cover of the book, but I may be confusing it with some other book I read.

Comment: My first thought is "Imposter" by Philip K. Dick, but that's a short story, not a book, and I don't think there's a bunker.

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for *Keith Laumer's*  **A Plague of Demons**. Originally published in 1965.There are the seven foot tall skull-faced aliens who mind control people into not seeing them, John Bravais, the agent who's augmented and able to resist their control, the underground bunker/facility that the agent is holding up in and the aliens trying to blast their way in, which I believe was in the States and not in England.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another Keith Laumer story, "[The Night of the Trolls](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?59344)" matches some elements of your question.

> a person or people who were sleeper agents that either awoke to
> discover this rule

In this story, the protagonist awakes from decades of suspended animation to discover that the world is in a post-apocalyptic state.

> it culminated in this person or persons discovering an underground
> facility or weapon

The protagonist awakes in an underground NASA? or military? base.

> I seem to remember a device or missile in this facility or bunker.

He battles the local warlord and eventually ends up launching a rocket (starship) from an underground launch silo.

Comment: I don't think it's "The Night of the Trolls."  I remember the world wasn't in a post-apocalyptic state.  And, from my fainting memory, it seems the protagonist was going about life as normal.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Even negative results help...in SCIENCE!